# How to avoid negative value in clock counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a countdown clock for quiz module so whenever the counter ends up I get a negative value. After the end of the timer I am getting -1 :-1 and I want it as 00:00.
I thought there would be an error in the total time but I am not able to figure out the error

I have tried this logic but it's not working

```
<script>
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
var clock = document.getElementById(id);
var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if($('.minutes').text() == '00' && $('.seconds').text() == '00')
    {
      if(score == 0)
          {
            // Wrap every letter in a span
            document.getElementById("congrats").innerHTML = "Better Luck Next time"; //When all the words are solved, greeting is displayed
            document.getElementById("part1").hidden = false;
                  document.getElementById("goodjob").hidden = false;
                  document.getElementById("part2").hidden = false;
                  document.getElementById("button5").disabled = true;


              document.getElementById("totscore").innerHTML = "Total correct answer " + score;
                    document.getElementById("totcoins").innerHTML = "Total coins achieved " + score;
                    document.getElementById("coins").hidden = false;
                    document.getElementById("my_audio").pause();
            setTimeout(function(){ 
            document.getElementById("drop").play(); 
            }, 1000)
          }
          else if(score == 5){
            document.getElementById("congrats").innerHTML = "Congratulations You solved all three piece words"; //When all the words are solved, greeting is displayed
            document.getElementById("part1").hidden = false;
                  document.getElementById("goodjob").hidden = false;
                  document.getElementById("part2").hidden = false;


              document.getElementById("totscore").innerHTML = "Total correct answer " + score;
                    document.getElementById("totcoins").innerHTML = "Total coins achieved " + score;
                    document.getElementById("coins").hidden = false;
                    document.getElementById("my_audio").pause();
            setTimeout(function(){ 
            document.getElementById("drop").play(); 
            }, 1000)
          }

    }

    if (t.total <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
}

updateClock();
var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 20 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
</script>
```

My HTML Code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
<div class="row" style="width:100%">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="clockdiv">
            <div>
                <span class="minutes"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="seconds"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="score-box" id="scoring">
            Your Score is 0
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function runs once more after reaching 0, thus resulting in -1.

You can fix it quickly by making a check in the function to get the remaining time:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    minutes = minutes < 0? 0 : minutes; //Check if they are lower than 0, if yes, set them to 0
    seconds = seconds < 0? 0 : seconds;

    return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use the string you put in the html to verify a number, use actual numbers. I'm referring to

```
if($('.minutes').text() == '00' && $('.seconds').text() == '00')
```

Avoid doing this.

You put a value inside the object you return from `getTimeRemaining` that represent the actual difference in milliseconds between the dates. Why not use that?

```
if (t.total <= 0) {
    ...
}
```

You need to check this *before* you put the time in the HTML.

EDIT: you're actually doing this at the end of `updateClock`, just check it before printing, and if <= 0 manually set the html to read 00:00.

```
function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    if (t.total <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timeinterval);
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = '00';
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = '00';
        if(score == 0) {
            ...
        }
        ....
    } else {
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious about the downvote. What did I say wrong?

Comment: I haven't down voted, but here are some of my findings: You don't need to convert it to number `$('.minutes').text()` & `$('.seconds').text()` hold formatted numbers. The author might want to differ between `"00"` and `"0"`. The second argument is kind of wrong - it is the number of **milliseconds** in difference. And the author might want to only check for seconds not milliseconds. The third thing is that your third line adds extra bulk to the code. Also generally, you did not answer what happens, so that it results in `-1`.

Comment: I didn't say you have to convert to numbers, I said it makes no sense to convert it to text and *then* use that text to check it's not zero (or less). Just check the number. I'm not sure what you mean about the difference in milliseconds. If it's zero or below zero, it doesn't matter whether they are seconds or milliseconds. The time is up anyway. Also I'm not sure what my third line is that adds bulk to the code. Can you please point it out? If you mean the `if` condition, I just moved it from the bottom of the function.

Comment: Where does he convert it to text? At least not in the code piece you quoted. I meant difference given from `Date.parse(...) - Date.parse(...)` is in milliseconds not in seconds. Even though it might make no difference, you gave wrong information and in some edge cases it might make one. With bulk, I mean the duplication of the `minutesSpan.innerHTML` part. While not being wrong and not a huge problem, some people might not like it. Also, note that I am not trying to nitpick or anything. I think your answer is not wrong per se. I just try to be helpful and point out its flaws.

Comment: Don't worry, I appreciate your comments. Anyway, the conversion to string happens with `minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);` which is then read back in the `if` condition. That's what I'm pointng at. Regarding the milliseconds, in what case do you think this can result in a wrong outcome? Regarding the added bulk, if you mean the one that sets them to "00", it's not added, I just moved it from outside the `if` and used it to avoid displaying the wrong numbers, or to the `else` condition to display the current time.

Comment: 1) Oh, you are right, I did not see that. 2) To be fair, I did not read the question fully and thought, that your answer is original code. My mistake. Your answer seems technically correct (would still change it from seconds to milliseconds, because while not being relevant to this question, it technically is wrong information). Have my up vote :)

Comment: For the life of me I couldn't understand why you kept saying that thing about milliseconds until I re-read my answer and noticed "represent the actual difference in **seconds** between the dates". I fixed it, thanks for pointing it out.